# How to fetch data from SOAP Webservice in Android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp, ksoap2

I'm having a parameterised SOAP webservice created, I need to consume in Android using any java or kotlin.

I tried using retrofit,okhttps and also with ksoap2 but I was unsuccessfull.
Is there any other method  to fetch SOAP webservice or else nothing is there?

Comment: Back in the olden days when I was using SOAP with java I was using [apache axis](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html). I liked the feature where it could generate a java model from the WSDL of a soap service

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.